# What to do with too broad questions on triage?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I can't find references on how to mark 'too broad' questions in the review section:

Do I have to mark it as «Requires Editing» or «Unsalvageable»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closeable == Unsalvageable, and too broad being a close reason, you just need to click "Unsalvageable" and you get the flag dialog, where you can select "close > too broad". Requires editing shouldn't be used for closeable questions.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear... I don't search a definition of «too broad» :) I tried the **review section** of stackoverflow, and I don't know how to mark the questions that are too broad: I have to mark-it as «Requires Editing» or «Unsalvageable»? or simply skip-it? (Or I don't understand the mechanism of review section, maybe....)

Comment: @fusion3k if you click on the "unsalvageable" option it will bring up the flagging dialog, where you can flag the question for closure as braiam explained.